# Are we blacklisted from Ubuntu repository?

Tags: apt, 22.04

I am working in a school and we are facing a strange problem since 2 weeks.
It has been impossible to join archive.ubuntu.com or make an apt update / upgrade.
We are working with network engineers to find what can happen, but it seems there is nothing that block us inside our network.
That's why we are wondering if it is posisble to be blacklisted by Ubuntu.
Can anyone help us to investigate or find a way to ask Ubuntu if our IPs are really blacklisted?
I put a screen capture on what we get when we try apt update.
Kind regards,
[image: apt update]

Comment: Networks in schools frequently block a whole bunch of stuff from known malware to adult sites to sites like vpn providers or open proxies.  My university blocks pastebin!

It's plausible that whatever filtering tool they're using is also blocking Ubuntu because someone at the filtering company (not the school) thought it contained software that could help bypass network blocks.  So even though your school's network engineers deny it is blocked, I wouldn't be surprised if it's something like that.

Comment: It could be blocked at the upstream provider that provides your school's connection, especially if they're specifically set up for schools

Comment: Thank you, we really are working with the network guys, and we have tried lot of things, even bypass every IPS and Firewall rules. They are trying to understand what could block this from our network. I don't think they are playing with us on this issue because they don't have time to lose with that. It is possibly a problem on our network but we didn't find what could do that. Everything else is working well.

Comment: Have you tried using a mirror? Or opening the URLs in a browser?

Comment: Have a look at a traceroute maybe?  And try tunneling (through a vpn or something)?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It doesn't seem to be a L3 problem, but more like an application issue. But at least, I am quite sure it comes from an IPS or Firewall that we didn't see, or that someone didn't know. So it probably means that "aptitude" is blocked somewhere. I will close this subject because there is no solution here :)

Comment: The debian repository for apt-get blacklisted all or most of latinoamerica. Racists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be internal to our ISP. Hopefully Ubuntu hasn't blacklisted us.
Thank you for those to try to help.